# How to customize @RequestParam error 400 response in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, http-status-code-400

Is there a way to customize what gets displayed when a required `@RequestParam` is not sent to the request handler? I always get HTTP Status 400 with a description "*The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().*" in this case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there is a way you should catch `MissingServletRequestParameterException`

You can do it in several ways:

1)

```
   @ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestParameterException.class)
      public String handleMyException(Exception  exception) {
       return "yourErrorViewName";
              }
```

2)

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/pages/myError.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

How I solved my problem:

```
@ResponseBody
@ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestParameterException.class)
public Object missingParamterHandler(Exception exception) {
    // exception handle while specified arguments are not available requested service only. it handle when request is as api json service       
    return  new HashMap() {{ put("result", "failed"); put("type", "required_parameter_missing");}};
}
```