# How to globally handle 404 exception by returning a customized error page in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception

I need to return a customized error page for HTTP 404, but the code does not work. I already read the stackflow [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580509/how-to-write-a-proper-global-error-handler-with-spring-mvc-spring-boot),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580509/how-to-write-a-proper-global-error-handler-with-spring-mvc-spring-boot), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045124/how-to-customize-requestparam-error-400-response-in-spring-mvc) and different [online](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-3-mvc-exception-1) + [articles](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) but my case is quite different with those or at least I can not figure out the issue.

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.
```

For example, it is suggested to use an action name in web.xml to handle the exception, it might work but I think is not a good method of doing it.

I  used following combinations:

```
1)

@Controller   //for class
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) //for method

2)
 @Controller   //for class
 @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) //for method
 @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class) //for method

3)

@ControllerAdvice //for class
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) //for method

3)

@ControllerAdvice //for class
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) //for method

4)
 @ControllerAdvice   //for class
 @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) //for method
 @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class) //for method
```

**Code**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public String handleBadRequest(Exception exception) {
          return "error404";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DispatcherServlet` does not throw an exception by default, if it does not find the handler to process the request. So you need to explicitly activate it as below:

In web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

If you are using annotation based configuration:

```
dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
```

In the controller advice class:

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public String handleExceptiond(NoHandlerFoundException ex) {
    return "errorPage";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using annotations where should I have that line?

Comment: @Jack  Is the DispatcherServlet configured in web.XML?

Comment: Yes it is configured in web.xml

Comment: Then you only need to make the XML changes that I have mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @ResponseStatus annotation at the class level. At least it works for me.

```
@Controller
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
  ....  
}
```

Comment: It works thanks, but the problem is I should have separate class for each type of httpstatus.

Comment: Sorry not sure about that issue

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following in your **web.xml** to display an error page on 404. It will display **404.jsp** page in views folder inside WEB-INF folder.

```
 <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/404.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
```

Comment: Thanks but this page cannot be customized, I need to send a request to back-end to send a customized error page based on each request.